# Password-protected ssh keys - Only been asked for password once ever

Tags: security, ssh, rsa, gnome

I'm using an rsa-encrypted ssh key for accessing certain servers - the private key is password-protected.

I have used this type of configuration in the past, and I'm aware that using the gnome-keyring I should normally be asked to confirm the password for my key once per session.
However, **since I entered my password for the first time, I was never asked for it again**.

I can verify that the private key is password-protected, I have tried the same key on other machines (where I've been asked for the password) and I have changed the password through the gnome-keyring manager. Still, I'm not being asked for it since that first time!

Any idea what might be happening here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password of your rsa key is the same as the password for your username on the system where you were never asked for the password. When you log into gnome, the gnome-keyring will automatically use the user password if it matches the key password.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you very much :)
It also explains why I was asked for it on other systems. 

Especially if passwords get treated like that, I think it kind of beats the purpose of having a password at all...
*runs quick to change password to something different*

Comment: @Geekfish: If you think the answer is useful, you may upvote it. Welcome to SO, btw!

Comment: I tried to but I'm afraid my reputation is not high enough yet (I need 15 to upvote you!). Will do when I get the chance though!

Comment: @Geekfish: Oh, i forgot about that. Silly me!